# Looking for getting contacts syncing from Android phone to Server

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-adapter

I am loking for a account syncing with Android Account then getting contact from the phone to the Server. 
I have gone through certain links for the same but this helped me to getting My account into the Account & Sync Section [Link](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator) but not getting a way to procure contacts. 
Kindly help me in this regard as I am a beginner for this all concept, its quite similar concept that app like Justdial is already using it and whatsapp also picks up the contact list from the phone.